# Kendo(Telerik) Does not work with Areas in ASP .Net Core MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, telerik, asp.net-mvc-areas

I hope someone could handle my issue.

I am working on ASP.NET Core MVC, in which I have successfully added Telerik UI ASP.Net MVC(Kendo).

I can use now the wizard and widgets in _layout, But The problem is here, I am using the Area to separate my projects user!
Now when I try even to use simple widgets like Calendar, it is not showing anything!

I also read this ticket but nothing handy achieved! 
https://www.telerik.com/forums/cannot-use-kendo-within-areas

Comment: Welcome! Please add a minimum reproducible sample code. Check here how to ask better questions to get better answers https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Console errors? How and where are you loading kendo? Bundles?

Comment: The ticked you linked has two crucial steps: did you do them?

Comment: @SteveGreene Yeah some js bundles and scripts in the _layout and in startup.cs

Comment: @GaloisGirl I do them , but Not sure about the web.config

Comment: Push F12 and check your console. Does it say kendo undefined or similar? That would indicate you are incorrectly referencing the kendo libraries. Also, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1) "In its standard location, /Views/_ViewImports.cshtml doesn't apply to areas."